# R Call changing depending on whether variable is named or not in S3 Methods

Tags: r

I'm looking to deal with `call` evaluations but am out of my depth when it comes to S3 Methods. Basically, I am wondering why a variable that I pass to a function call is not evaluated but rather remains the name of the variable rather than it's value. And all of this depends on whether I name the variable in the function or not.

Let me illustrate with a short example:

I first create a quick function to create a sample class to be used with S3 Methods:

```r
create_myS3 <- function(a, b){
  out <- list()
  out$a <- a
  out$b <- b
  class(out) <- "myS3"
  return(out)
}
```

Now the set-up that I am interested in features a number of functions within each other. I first create an S3 method for this `myS3` class, let's call it `m` and we define a specific routine for the `myS3` class as well as a `default` method. Note that the `myS3` version calls the `default` version.

```r
m <- function(x, ...){UseMethod("m")}

m.myS3 <- function(x, estimator = NULL){
  y <- list()
  y$a <- x$a + 1
  y$b <- x$b + 1
  
  out <- m.default(y, 
                   estimator)
  return(out)
}

m.default <- function(x, estimator = NULL, ...){
  out <- list()
  out$call <- sys.call()
  out$result <- x$a - x$b
  out$aux$estimator <- estimator
  
  return(out)
}
```

Now that we have defined the functions, we can look at the results function that I'm interested in:

```r
h <- function(x){
  out <- list()
  out$result_call <- if(is.null(x$call$estimator)){"Success"}else{"Fail"}
  out$result_list <- if(is.null(x$aux$estimator)){"Success"}else{"Fail"}
  return(out)
}
```

It's entire purpose is to check whether the `estimator` element is in the object it is passed to and to give a message based on that.

Ok, now let's put it all together:

```r
g <- function(x){
  object <- m(x)
  out <- h(object)
  
  return(out)
}

initial <- create_myS3(10,5)
g(initial)
```

The `g()` function now calls `m()` on the input, which was created with the `create_myS3` function - so is of class `myS3` and is therefore passed to `m.myS3` before it is passed to `m.default`. The resulting object is then passed to `h()` - in all cases we have not set the `estimator` argument, which then defaults to `NULL` and both my check statements in `h()` return `Success`.

**Now all I do is change one tiny thing**: I now modify `m.myS3` to call the `m.default` not just with the order of the input variables **but now I also specify the option** - in my mind the more robust way. So to clarify, from this `m.default(y, estimator)` I change it to `m.default(x = y, estimator = estimator)`.

This change then changes my results from `h()` to `Fail` for the evaluation `if(is.null(x$call$estimator)){"Success"}else{"Fail"}` while `if(is.null(x$aux$estimator)){"Success"}else{"Fail"}` results in `Success`.

The reason for this is that the call statement evaluates to `estimator` rather than to its true value `NULL`.

Is there an easy way to evaluate this call to its true value (I have tried `eval` or `deparse`)? Or even better **is there are a way to ensure that in `m.myS3` the value is always passed rather than the variable?**

Here below is the total code for convenience:

```r
create_myS3 <- function(a, b){
  out <- list()
  out$a <- a
  out$b <- b
  class(out) <- "myS3"
  return(out)
}

m <- function(x, ...){UseMethod("m")}

m.myS3 <- function(x, estimator = NULL){
  y <- list()
  y$a <- x$a + 1
  y$b <- x$b + 1
  
  out <- m.default(y, 
                   estimator)
  return(out)
}

m.default <- function(x, estimator = NULL, ...){
  out <- list()
  out$call <- sys.call()
  out$result <- x$a - x$b
  out$aux$estimator <- estimator
  
  return(out)
}

h <- function(x){
  out <- list()
  out$result_call <- if(is.null(x$call$estimator)){"Success"}else{"Fail"}
  out$result_list <- if(is.null(x$aux$estimator)){"Success"}else{"Fail"}
  return(out)
}

g <- function(x){
  object <- m(x)
  out <- h(object)
  
  return(out)
}

initial <- create_myS3(10,5)
g(initial)
$result_call
[1] "Success"

$result_list
[1] "Success"

## Changing m.myS3 (only change is to name the option of function m.default)

m.myS3 <- function(x, estimator = NULL){
  y <- list()
  y$a <- x$a + 1
  y$b <- x$b + 1
  
  out <- m.default(x = y, 
                   estimator = estimator)
  return(out)
}

g(initial)
$result_call
[1] "Fail"

$result_list
[1] "Success"
```

Comment: There is a difference between `sys.call` and `match.call`. Please use `match.call` since you are working withing a function

Comment: can you change it to `out$call <- sys.call();
  tmp <-  as.list(out$call);
  tmp$estimator <- estimator;
 
  out$call <- as.call(tmp)` and then call `g(initial)`